# how can i get bluetooth rssi and link quality value in bluez?

Tags: android, linux, bluetooth, bluez

Is there anyone who knows how I can get bluetooth rssi and link quality values in bluez without any file and data transfered ?

I am using bluez in linux to make some bluetooth program.
but I got a question about bluetooth rssi and lq..
although I don't trasmit or receive any file or data, I can get rssi ,lq value in linux 
using hci_read_rssi,hci_read_lq.. 
just through pairing and connection between two bluetooth devices

my program is to transmit files at an odroid board based on linux to an android mobile phone
and check rssi and lq value at The odroid board

actually It is possible  I can get those values..
but I don't know how i can get rssi, lq eventhough Odroid board just sends a file

please let me know  if there is anyone who knows about that.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the following [link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=57893&p=438849) but to summarize you don't have to use pybluez:

install bluetooth by:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends bluetooth
```

You don't have to use pybluez, you can use the following to obtain rssi by the device mac address:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "testing rssi /n"> logs1
while (true)
do
hcitool rssi [MAC Address]>> logs1
date +%S
date +%S>> logs1
sleep 0.25
done
```

if you son't know the mac you can use:

```
hcitool scan
```